# Use months instead of year in D3plus.js .time()

Tags: d3.js, d3plus

I am using a d3plus.js for my project and the code I am using is as below
Link to demo [here](http://d3plus.org/examples/advanced/10754920/)

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="http://www.d3plus.org/js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.d3plus.org/js/d3plus.js"></script>

<div id="viz"></div>

<script>
  var sample_data = [
    {"year": 1991, "name":"alpha", "value": 15},
    {"year": 1992, "name":"alpha", "value": 20},
    {"year": 1994, "name":"alpha", "value": 30},
    {"year": 1995, "name":"alpha", "value": 60},
    {"year": 1993, "name":"beta", "value": 40},
    {"year": 1994, "name":"beta", "value": 60},
    {"year": 1995, "name":"beta", "value": 10},
    {"year": 1994, "name":"gamma", "value": 35},
    {"year": 1995, "name":"gamma", "value": 40}
  ]
  var visualization = d3plus.viz()
    .container("#viz")
    .data(sample_data)
    .type("tree_map")
    .id("name")
    .size("value")
    .time({"value": "year", "solo": 1994})
    .draw()
</script>
```

Here , I want to replace year with months . Like instead of 1991,1992 and so on, I need Jan,Feb,March etc.. Problem looks simple but just replacing dint work. Is there a way to do that?

Here is what I tried

```
<script>
  var sample_data = [
    {"month": 'jan', "name":"alpha", "value": 15},
    {"month": 'feb', "name":"alpha", "value": 20},
    {"month": 'march', "name":"alpha", "value": 30},
    {"month": 'april', "name":"alpha", "value": 60},
    {"month": 'may', "name":"beta", "value": 40},
    {"month": 'march', "name":"beta", "value": 60},
    {"month": 'april', "name":"beta", "value": 10},
    {"month": 'march', "name":"gamma", "value": 35},
    {"month": 'april', "name":"gamma", "value": 40}
  ]
  var visualization = d3plus.viz()
    .container("#viz")
    .data(sample_data)
    .type("tree_map")
    .id("name")
    .size("value")
    .time({"value": "month", "solo": "jan"})
    .draw()
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

```
<script>
  var sample_data = [
    {"month": "2012/05/21", "name":"alpha", "value": 15},
    {"month": "2012/05/21", "name":"alpha", "value": 20},
    {"month": "2012/06/21", "name":"alpha", "value": 30},
    {"month": "2012/06/21", "name":"gamma", "value": 60},
    {"month": "2012/08/21", "name":"gamma", "value": 40}
  ]
  var visualization = d3plus.viz()
    .container("#viz")
    .data(sample_data)
    .type("tree_map")
    .id("name")
    .size("value")
    .time({"value": "month", "solo": "2012/05/21"})
    .draw()
</script>
```